# Argument of type '(prev: cartDetailsTyp) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<cartDetailsTyp[]> in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting typescript error while updating state. Error is happening at setCart.

```
type cartDetailsTyp = {
  id: number;
  itemCode: number;
  quantity: number;
};

const [cart, setCart] = useState<cartDetailsTyp[]>([]);
const responseFromApi=  (parseInt(e.target.value));
setCart((prev) => [...prev,{...responseFromApi, quantity:1}])
```

responseFromApi is the below code
{id: 125, itemCode: 10111};

Comment: Typo? You use `Typ` in the declaration but `Type` where you use it.

Comment: Need some more information here. Your responseFromApi variable is referencing and event that I don't see anywhere so that's not going to work. If you're trying to Parse an entire object into an int that's also not going to work. You aren't using the spread operator correctly try reading the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: can you please rewrite the code